# Best practice: declaring global arrays of fixed length automatically

Tags: c, arrays, variable-declaration, avr-gcc

I have a data structure that I want to share globally between files in the project.

```
mystruct_s data[] = {
    { // element 1
    }, { // element 2 ...
    }, { 0 } // element N is zero to mark array end
}
```

Within the same file, objects refer to `data`.  Its type is read as `mystruct_s[N]`.  This is nice and straighforward.

In the header file, I have:

```
mystruct_s data[];
```

In other files, I get a type mismatch warning, because it is assumed to mean a 1-element array.

I am counting length based on array contents, so I don't need to know `sizeof`.  A good old fashioned pointer `mystruct_s*` would do.

1. How can I propagate the length of the array into another file, automatically?  This is a maintenance nightmare if I have to manually count every single element and put that count into the header.

   - Should I just declare it with some random-ass number anyway, and #pragma ignore the warning?
2. How can I declare the array itself as an unknown or single-element array (any will do) or pointer?

   - I don't need a pointer variable, and it seems this is complicated by also doing this on the AVR platform, where the array shall be stored in PROGMEM.  If I declare a pointer, it wants to put the *pointer variable* in PROGMEM.  Which isn't very useful.  And then the array it points to, becomes an unnamed object somewhere.  (The compiler (GCC 8.1.0) doesn't like this, so I'm not sure what exactly it thinks I'm trying..)
3. How *should* I approach this, if this is the wrong way?  Throw everything in the header?  (I do like to use header files for blocks of data, but I prefer to do that on blocks that I don't need to maintain; because these elements reference other objects in the .c file, it is more natural to place `data[]` there too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred way to declare global variables and make them known in other modules is as follows:

```
// to define global variables, use the following:

// module.c
#include "glo.h"

// glo.h
#ifndef EXTERN
# define EXTERN extern
#endif
EXTERN int myvar;

#define ARR_SIZE 123
EXTERN int myArr[ARR_SIZE];

// main.c
#define EXTERN
#include "glo.h"
```

This alocates storage for the globals in `main` and makes them known as `extern` in all other modules.

This expands to:

```
// module.c
extern int myvar;
extern int myArr[123];
```

and in main:

```
// main.c allocates storage
int myvar;
int myArr[123];
```

**EDIT**

You have a requirement to know the array size not through a defined constant but as the size of the array based on the initializers.Possibly a good way is to define the array with a dummy size for all other modules and to provide the array size as a separate global variable that you initialize in main, after the initialization.

```
// glo.h
#ifndef EXTERN
# define EXTERN extern
extern int myArr[2];
#endif
EXTERN int gArrSize;
```

and:

```
// main.c
#define EXTERN
#include "glo.h"
int myArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 0};
int gArrSize= sizeof(myArr)/sizeof(myArr[0]);
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the upper case EXTERN?

Comment: To indicate it is a macro (a `#define`d symbol).

Comment: I mean why not just `extern int myvar;`? Or am I missing the point here?

Comment: You are missing the point: consider including in main and in a module: where will the actual storage be allocated?

Comment: What is the significance of `extern` here? Can this be done without ARR_SIZE, or with it calculated automatically?

Comment: Oh, now I get what you are doing. I do not like it, but I get it ;)

Comment: I see your point, Tim. As the actual array has a terminator (the null entry), you could use a dummy size in other modules and an initializer in your main module. You can make the actual array size known to other modules as a separate global variable that you initialize in main as `int gArrSize=sizeof(myArr)/sizeof(myArr[0])`

Comment: Just trying this; everything seems okay with `extern` alone (no define hi-jinx).  `mystruct_s data[];` produces the one-element warning, while `extern mystruct_s data[];` produces no warning and seems to work fine!

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your "array" in a higher level struct

```
struct higherlevel {
    mystruct_s *data;
    size_t datalen;
};
```